# I have a 1994 pontiac grand am gt with wipers not working

Tags: pontiac, windshield-wipers, grand-am

I can not get the wipers to work. Ive replaced the motor but there is no power to the fuse and i put a new one in today

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

There are fusible links that feed the fuse panel, they are connected at the starter battery terminal, if there is not 12v at the washer fuse then one of these fusible links is broken, blown or not connected on the last starter change.

[image]

.

.

.

[image]

Comment: Is there a relay somewhere?

Comment: Not any outside of the washer motor assembly, just a fuse, and the wiper switch assembly. See my added image above.

Comment: Ok i just replaced the motor but there is still no voltage at the fuse what else would cause that

Comment: Then it is most likely a fusible link as I explained in my answer.

Comment: I checked all the fusible links and one was bad but after i fixed it. The wipers still do not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the lack of supply to the fuse.

Are there other items not working?

Temporarily bridging a supply will enable testing of the new motor.

This could be a damaged fuse box or loose connector or broken wire.

Comment: The radio is not working too and all the wires still have the factory wrap around them. Is there a relay somewhere because thats what my mobile mechanic said last night to check but i dont know where it is